# .net core web api controller and action selection

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to generate appropriate 404 erors according to:

1. If requesting controller doesn't exist;
2. If action doesn't exist;

I'm trying to migrate web api on .NET Core Web API and need to find analog in .net core of DefaultHttpControllerSelector and ApiControllerActionSelector , which was in .net framework. Because I have modules, which checks controller and action existance. And generate custom error if controller or action haven't found. 
How I can handle this?

Comment: Can you define "appropriate"? Try to be more specific about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @KirkLarkin , post was edited

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#understanding-iactionconstraint Sounds like you need to fully customize the routing.

Comment: Why in the world do you need this in the first place? If there's no matching controller/action, you'll already get a 404. That's built-in.

Answer (score 1):

For controller or action not exist, it will return **404** by default.

If you want to custom the Error Message, you could try `Middleware` to check the `Response.StatusCode` and then custom the reponse based on your own logic.

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.Use(async (context, next) => {
            //handle request
            await next.Invoke();
            //handle response
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
            {
                //hanlde based on your logic
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Something wrong");
            }
        });
  // Rest app.Use
```

Comment: I know that i will get 404 by default if controller or action not exist. I did the same approach, but I thought that i can handle 404  and make throw new Exception("Controller is absent")  and  throw new Exception("Action is absent")

Comment: You may try implement `IRouter` and override `RouteAsync` to valid whether the controller or action exist. try [RouteBase](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/3a022107dcba43fb6441a5fad741537f17a5fd17/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/RouteBase.cs).